# Chilitags compilation on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, computer-vision

anyone has any experience with Chilitags? I tried to implemented it on my Virtual Linux, I followed all the steps the instructions give, but when I tried to make build it gave this error.

```
     cc1plus: error: unrecgonized command line options `-std=c++11`
```

Can somebody tell me what this error means. My cmake version is 2.8.7 and gcc version is 4.6.3.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of GCC do you have? Even if you say it's the latest it might help us knowing exactly which version it is so we might be able to test it better. Also, if you have typos in your question, you should edit it and fix those typos.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, my gcc version is 4.6.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC version 4.6 is *far* from the latest version, it's up to 4.9 now.

The problem is that the flag `-std=c++11` didn't get into GCC until version 4.7, before that it was `-std=c++0x`.

You might also want to know that the support for C++11 (or C++0x as it was still called then) was far from complete in GCC 4.6.

Comment: It's just a typing mistake, it's not the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think this should be the problem. I tried to install gcc 4.9 on ubuntu using following command lines.

      sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9

But is gives an error like this, 

E: Unable to locate package g++-4.9
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-4.9'

Any clue what's wrong, my ubuntu version is 12.04.4

Thanks a lot.